# How do I stream HuggingFacePipeline output to a LangChain Dataframe Agent?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, streamlit, langchain, huggingface

I'm trying to mimic the LangChain Agent + Streamlit demo outlined [in this documentation](https://python.langchain.com/docs/integrations/callbacks/streamlit), except with a local HuggingFace model using the `HuggingFacePipeline` and Langchain Dataframe Agent.

I am very close to matching the original functionality, save for one thing: I cannot figure out how to stream the model's thoughts and actions. My Streamlit page stops at `Thinking...` until the model completes its inference, after which the result of that Agent-Model cycle appears and the next cycle begins.

I tried using `TextStreamer` and `TextIteratorStreamer`, but they don't seem to work correctly with the Agent. I also tried to put the `StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()` callback into the `HuggingFacePipeline` which had no effect.

Here is the relevant code:

```py
@st.cache_resource
def getLangChainPipeline(model_config: dict):
    # model_config simply contains the name, path, etc of the HF model

    # Loading the model and tokenizer
    USE_CUSTOM_MODEL = True
    CUSTOM_MODEL_PATH = model_config['path']

    MODEL_PATH = (
        CUSTOM_MODEL_PATH if USE_CUSTOM_MODEL else model_config['name']
    )

    extra_args = {}
    if cuda_available:
        extra_args['device_map'] = 'auto'

    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_config['name'], trust_remote_code=model_config['trust_remote_code'])
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(MODEL_PATH, 
                                                torch_dtype=torch.float16, 
                                                trust_remote_code=model_config['trust_remote_code'],
                                                **extra_args)
    
    # for inference
    model.eval()

    # tried using TextStreamer but that didn't work
    streamer = TextStreamer(tokenizer, skip_prompt=True)

    pipe = pipeline(
        "text-generation", 
        model=model, 
        tokenizer=tokenizer, 
        # streamer=streamer,
        max_new_tokens=200, 
        trust_remote_code=model_config['trust_remote_code'],
    )

    # tried using callbacks=[StreamingStdOutCallbackHandler()] below which didn't work either
    return HuggingFacePipeline(pipeline=pipe)

# load pipeline
with st.spinner('Loading model...'):
    hf = getLangChainPipeline(codellama_13b_instruct)

# create agent
agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(hf, df, verbose=True)

# form for using to type prompt
with st.form(key="form"):
    "Working with 50000 rows of sample data."
    user_input = st.text_input("Query")
    submit_clicked = st.form_submit_button("Submit Question")

# run Agent when submit is clicked
if submit_clicked:
    with st.empty():
        st.chat_message("user").write(user_input)
        with st.chat_message("assistant"):
            st_callback = StreamlitCallbackHandler(st.container())
            response = agent.run(user_input, callbacks=[st_callback])
            st.info(response)
```

I would appreciate any help figuring this out.